# Android Autobahn Error "WebSockets protocol violation"

Tags: java, android, websocket, jetty, autobahn

I use Jetty - on server, Android Autobahn - on client. When i try send from server large data (most 150 000 bytes), I receive error in client: "WebSockets protocol violation". But server call "writeSuccess()" handler. If i send less 150 000 bytes, then works.

How to send large data?